# c++ cvShowImage error

Tags: opencv, c-api

I want to load an image with opencv. Everything is working properly but it doesn't show me the image. Code what I usin is here:
     #include 
     #include 
     #include

```
 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

 int main( int argc, const char** argv )
 {
     IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("D:/C++/ MGC.JPG");

     cvNamedWindow("MyWindow", 1); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
     cvMoveWindow("MyWindow", 100, 100);
     cvShowImage("MyWindow", img);

     cvWaitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress
     cvDestroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you chose to use the C interface? If not, you should be using the C++ interface

```
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("D:/C++/ MGC.JPG");
    cv::namedWindow("MyWindow", 256);
    cv::imshow("MyWindow", image );
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of opencv are you using? What header files have you included? `#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"`

Comment: I use opencv 2.3. I included  #include <opencv/cv.h>
 #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
 #include <opencv/highgui.h>

Comment: If I use tese libraries #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp, then I have same problem as before

Comment: what error as before? compilation error or the images not showing?